# How to disable attribute checking in WebStorm? Attribute is not allowed here

Tags: javascript, html, jsx, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have created a library that extends the capabilities of HTML (jsx)
Now I can add styles to props.

But WebStorm doesn't know about it and circles all custom attributes.

I can click "add maxWidth to custom html attributes" but I have to add a lot of them.

How to turn off attribute checking?

[image: https://ibb.co/zRY610q]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Disable an inspection in the settings**﻿

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the IDE settings and select Editor |
   Inspections.
2. Locate the inspection you want to disable, and clear the checkbox
   next to it.
3. Apply the changes and close the dialog.